# FileNotFoundException when starting a background download even though file clearly exists

Tags: windows-runtime

In my WinRT application I have the following code:

```
                resultingFile = await downloadFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

                var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
                var operation = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(rendition.Url), resultingFile);

                await operation.StartAsync();
```

After the `CreateFileAsync` call I can verify that I do have a 0byte file at the filename path (and double verified by pulling the location out of the `resultingFile` itself.

However, when `operation.StartAsync()` is called I get a `FileNotFoundException` claiming the system could not find the file specified.  Unfortunately, that's all it tells me and there is no inner exception.

I have also verified that `rendition.Url` gives me a valid url that downloads the content I'm expecting to be downloading.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: please give us more info, the source Url is a public link or a private/corporate site? Have you tested that link in a 'browser private' session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this code isn't what is throwing the error but it's some code the BackgroundDownloader uses to coordinate things that can't find it's own file.

Uninstalling the application and redeploying it fixed it.

Good waste of 3 hours :(